# Software or library which can be used for sorting PDF files

Tags: pdf

I'm sorting a lot of PDFs files(most of them are academic papers) and am looking for a software which can atuomatically detect and extract titles, authors, and refrences. Is there any software or library like this?

Comment: I suggest that "cataloguing" (or similar) may be a more precise term to include in the question, as opposed to sorting which implies rearranging your files.

Comment: For which operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) is specifically designed for this sort of work that you are doing with online & desktop clients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) is excellent for this purpose, since it automatically extracts metadata from PDFs and organizes them for you in a library.

[image: zotero library screenshot showing library and import function]

Unlike Mendeley, it is open source. You can use it either as a Firefox add-on or a standalone application:

https://www.zotero.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

If the titles, authors, references contain any strings that indicate what they are, you might be able to use the [pdf2text library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2text), which simply extracts all strings from PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [All My Books](http://www.bolidesoft.com/allmybooks.html) program for managing my e-books including e-books in PDF format. May be this program can help you. However, it does not analyzing the contents, it extracts meta-data (title, author) automatically if it is available. Also, it uses the first page of the document as a cover thumbnail. Use menu item "Book - Scan drive for books..." to find your PDF files and add them in a batch mode. After that, you you can browse the documents either by cover thumbnails or by title list. You can sort by any field if they are not empty.